# How can I extract the files from a .rar archive protected by password, using SharpCompress?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharpcompress

I want to extract the files from a given .rar archive, which is password protected. I have the following:

```
pwd = "password";
srs = @"c:\path\file.rar"
des = @"c:\path\folder"

using (var archive = RarArchive.Open(srs, new ReaderOptions() { Password = pwd }))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    entry.WriteToDirectory(des, new ExtractionOptions()
                    {
                        ExtractFullPath = true,
                        Overwrite = true
                    });
                }
```

but it extracts the files corrupted, both when the password is correct and incorrect.

Comment: Can you share the RAR file? Have you tried with other RAR files?

Comment: @mjwills I tried with other rar files, and any of them extract properly.

Comment: Can you share the RAR file?

Comment: This is a test file I made.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a644c27d2fecde35c38892dfe92a60ff20200729190847/4edb66